# Android NDK app failed to load library

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

My native library code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

jstring Java_com_mindtherobot_samples_ndkfoo_NdkFooActivity_invokeNativeFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis) {
  return env->NewStringUTF("Hello from native code!");
}
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libpacman
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("libpacman");
    }

    // declare the native code function - must match main.cpp
    private native String invokeNativeFunction();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // this is where we call the native code
        String hello = invokeNativeFunction();

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(hello).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Library is compiled successfully and libpacman.so is in libs/armeabi directory, but logcat says:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13060): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(13060): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(13060):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13060):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
E/AndroidRuntime(13060):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
E/AndroidRuntime(13060):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
E/AndroidRuntime(13060):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
E/AndroidRuntime(13060):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(13060):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
E/AndroidRuntime(13060):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(13060):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(13060):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
E/AndroidRuntime(13060):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13060):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(13060):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
E/AndroidRuntime(13060):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime(13060):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13060): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load libpacman: findLibrary returned null
E/AndroidRuntime(13060):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
E/AndroidRuntime(13060):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
E/AndroidRuntime(13060):    at com.example.pacman.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:11)
E/AndroidRuntime(13060):    ... 15 more
W/ActivityManager(  315):   Force finishing activity com.example.pacman/.MainActivity
```

So, system can not find the library, but if unzip APK file - it's in the lib directory. Why not in the libs?

Edit.
OK, now i fixed the package names:

```
jstring Java_com_wiagames_pacman_MainActivity_invokeNativeFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis) {
  return env->NewStringUTF("Hello from native code!");
}
```

Android.mk and MainActivity.java are the same. Package is com.wiagames.pacman everywhere. But I'm getting error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(23084): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(23084): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(23084):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(23084):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
E/AndroidRuntime(23084):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
E/AndroidRuntime(23084):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
E/AndroidRuntime(23084):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
E/AndroidRuntime(23084):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(23084):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
E/AndroidRuntime(23084):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(23084):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(23084):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
E/AndroidRuntime(23084):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(23084):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(23084):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
E/AndroidRuntime(23084):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime(23084):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(23084): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load libpacman: findLibrary returned null
E/AndroidRuntime(23084):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
E/AndroidRuntime(23084):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
E/AndroidRuntime(23084):    at com.wiagames.pacman.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:13)
E/AndroidRuntime(23084):    ... 15 more
W/ActivityManager(  315):   Force finishing activity com.wiagames.pacman/.MainActivity
```

Comment: The safe way to create your jni header file is that write your native methods signature on .java file, and so, run the `javah -jni your.package.name.YourClassName` on `bin/classes` folder. Maybe the signature of your posted function is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my experiences in NDK,the path of your class in Android App must be the same as

```
Java_com_mindtherobot_samples_ndkfoo_NdkFooActivity_invokeNativeFunction



Java_com_mindtherobot_samples_ndkfoo [package name]
NdkFooActivity [activity or class name]
invokeNativeFunction [function name]
```

Comment: Checked one more time - the package name is com.wiagames.pacman everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Your classname is visibly not `NdkFooActivity`. Also make sure that your java package is `com.mindtherobot.samples.ndkfoo`. The name of native function and the Java context from which are you calling it must be in sync. Normally you would produce the native header with `javah -jni` which works *on the already compiled class*, not the java sources.

Answer (score 4):

The library name you pass to `System.loadLibrary()` should simply be `pacman`, not `libpacman`.