# Android SDK app failed to load library

Tags: android, java-native-interface, rdp

Heyho. I've got the same error message as this guy:
"[Android NDK app failed to load library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022990/android-ndk-app-failed-to-load-library/15249091#15249091)"
and i'm trying to transfer these answers here on my situation for hours now, but it doesnt work.
Can someone help me?
It's this opensource project here, which i want to try to get it run on my emulator.
https://github.com/itskewpie/FreeRDP-android

FreeRDPActivity.java

```
package net.itskewpie.freerdp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FreeRDPActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    } 
    static {       
        System.loadLibrary("freerdp");
    }  
}
```

freerdp.c

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <freerdp/freerdp.h>

jstring Java_net_itskewpie_freerdp_FreeRDPActivity_test(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz )
{
    android_main();      
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "HELLO");
}
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

MY_LIBS_PATH=freerdp-1.0-nevo/libs/armeabi-v7a
LOCAL_MODULE    := freerdp-utils
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(MY_LIBS_PATH)/libfreerdp-utils.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/freerdp-1.0-nevo/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
...
```

Error Message:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load freerdp from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/net.itskewpie.freerdp-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/net.itskewpie.freerdp-2]: findLibrary returned null
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
net.itskewpie.freerdp.FreeRDPActivity.<clinit>(FreeRDPActivity.java:16)
... 15 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out this open source project:

[www.freerdp.com](http://www.freerdp.com)

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy the Android.mk exactly as in the github project? Did you copy the relevant libraries too?

```
    #
    ## libfreerdp.so
    #
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE := freerdp
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := freerdp.c
    LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
    NDK_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT=/opt/android-toolchain
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := freerdp-utils
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += freerdp-locale
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += freerdp-crypto
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += freerdp-sspi
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += freerdp-codec
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += freerdp-core
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += freerdp-cache
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += freerdp-gdi
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += freerdp-rail
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += freerdp-channels
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += rdpsnd_alsa
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cliprdr
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += rdpsnd
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += freerdp_android
```

In the Java side, it looks like you should load the other libraries as well, in the appropriate order:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("freerdp-utils");
    System.loadLibrary("freerdp-codec");
    System.loadLibrary("freerdp-gdi");
    System.loadLibrary("freerdp-core");
    System.loadLibrary("freerdp-rail");
    System.loadLibrary("freerdp-chche");
    System.loadLibrary("freerdp-crypto");
    System.loadLibrary("freerdp-sspi");
    System.loadLibrary("freerdp-channels");
    System.loadLibrary("rdpsnd_alsa");
    System.loadLibrary("cliprdr");
    System.loadLibrary("rdpsnd");
    System.loadLibrary("freerdp_android");
    System.loadLibrary("freerdp");
}
```

Comment: yes, i copied it exactly as in the github project. loaded the other librarys, but it's ending in the same error message.

Comment: @trek711 Did you run the ndk-build command in the jni folder? Your error says that android can't find the freerdp library. By running the ndk-build you generate all the libraries needed in the appropiate directories.